# Why Android Launcher picks a low-density icon?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I've created 2 kinds of launcher icons:

```
mipmap-mdpi (48x48)
mipmap-hdpi (72x72)
```

Now I'm checking out what kind of icon Lollipop's Launcher chooses. And it chooses the `mdpi` icon, and then stretches the icon up to 60x60px:

#### Demo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCfkn.png]

The question is:

> Why the Launcher picks `mdpi` instead of `hdpi`?

Comment: did you try on other devices with lolipop version ?

Answer (score 0):

By default it takes the lower size icon.
So, if you want to use large pixel icon then give some different name.

for exp:
Use two icons of different size and give same name and put it to any extension folder like `mdp`i,`ldpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi` or `xxhdpi`. It will always prefer smallest size.

Comment: I didn't understand... What's the solution you're suggesting?

Answer (score -1):

The launcher sometimes picks the mdpi icon instead of hdpi icon because of the custom theme applied on the device, or because of the custom launcher.

if you are using the default launcher by your device brand you can use some other custom launcher you will definitely be shocked to see the results